# Remove quotes for value that has integer value in the dictionary

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i have a json dictionary, i want to remove the quotes from the integer values throughout the json data.

```
[
  {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": "8.0"
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": "90"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

when i pass the above object to a function (i.e)

```
def remove_quote_for_int_values(obj):
    print(expected_output_is_below)
    pass
```

The above is the json data i want to achieve something like below

```
[
  {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 90
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's a pretty strange JSON object if integer values are represented as string there.

But you can do the following:

1. If you know what fields are integer:

```py
def remove_quote_for_int_values(obj, fields):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [remove_quote_for_int_values(el, fields) for el in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        result = {}
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
                result[key] = remove_quote_for_int_values(value, fields)
            elif key in fields:
                result[key] = int(value)  # or the desired type (e.g. float)
            else:
                result[key] = value
        return result
    else:
        return obj
```

2. If you don't know

```py
def remove_quote_for_int_values(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [remove_quote_for_int_values(el) for el in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        result = {}
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
                result[key] = remove_quote_for_int_values(value)
            else:
                try:
                    value = float(value)  # or any desired type
                except ValueError:  # TypeError when converting to `int`
                    pass
                result[key] = value
        return result
    else:
        return obj
```

Both solutions should work with nested objects too.

Comment: i dont know which fields, so ur 2point answer is asking for fields in the arguments

Comment: Hello, I fixed the solution. The second one works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty and there is probably a simpler and more effective way of doing this, but this works:

```
def remove_quote_for_int_values(obj):
    for book in obj:
        for book_info in book.values():
            for elem in book_info:
                for key, value in elem.items():
                    if value.isdigit():
                        elem[k] = int(value)
```

Output:

```
[{'book': [{'category': 'reference', 'author': 'Nigel Rees', 'title': 'Sayings of the Century', 'price': 8}, {'category': 'fiction', 'author': 'Evelyn Waugh', 'title': 'Sword of Honour', 'price': 90}]}]
```